# How to reference to an image in another folder?

Tags: css, image, path

I have a style sheet at `../mytheme/css/layouts/mystyle.css`. I'd like to reference to an image at `../mytheme/images/myimage.png`. However, when I use this path in the `mystyle.css` file, the computer is looking for the picture at `../mytheme/css/images/myimage.png`, which is wrong.

How can I set the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the relative path inside `mystyle.css` should be

```
../../images/myimage.png
```

---

You start from `layout` folder, so

`../` up to *css* folder
`../` up to *mytheme* folder
`images/` enter the *image* folder

then pick the right image